# Integrating TFS and MySQL

Tags: mysql, tfs

We are developing an application with **Visual Studio 2008** and **TFS**. Our database is a **MySQL** DB. As we develop we keep the new queries that need to be applied to the database of our new release as the **New Version Update Queries**. Right now I'm keeping them in a simple text file (which is a painful task!). I know that TFS integrates with MSSQL and makes this job very easy. I've already asked our consultant from Microsoft if there is any way to integrate TFS and MySQL, and his answer was "NO". So I was wondering if anyone knows any smart way of handling this issue?

Comment: Just use MSSQL.

NO, TFS doesn't work with MySQL, why would it.

On the other hand, why are you using TFS to begin with??!!

Comment: We use TFS as the source-control; it has all the tools that we require to manage the source-code and developers' tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question may be a little misleading in that I think you're saying TFS when you mean Visual Studio.  My guess is that you are looking for a MySQL provider to hook into VS2008 so you can use the database developer features (DataDude) with it?  TFS itself is simply a server that provides source control and work item tracking services and isn't designed to work with anything other than MSSQL.

Visual Studio's data tools can be hooked into other databases using the Database Schema Provider interfaces (it's a 2010 feature).  An implementation exists [for Oracle](http://toadextensions.com/index.jspa), but nothing yet exists for MySQL.

My suggestion would be to store your scripts in TFS as regular source controlled items, and keep doing what you are doing until someone writes a DSP for MySQL.