# To maintain version control for MySQL in TFS Source Control

Tags: mysql, tfs

Our requirement is we need to maintain the changes that do in MySQL database in version control.

We checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814265/store-a-mysql-database-in-source-control). We understand that we need to install Visual Studio and [mysql .net connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and we need to use Visual Studio to integrate with TFS. Please suggest.

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448564/integrating-tfs-and-mysql) we noticed that TFS will not work with MySQL. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MySQL .NET Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/) is a driver for .NET applications to communicate with MySQL servers. It can't be used directly for version control of MySQL in TFS Source Control.

Alternatively, you can commit scripts that change your database to TFS Source Control to track changes. For example, you could write scripts that modify your database and then commit those scripts to TFS Source Control. This way, you can keep a history of changes made to your database.

Comment: For example, you could write scripts that modify your database and then commit those scripts to TFS Source Control - Are you telling that we need to create a file and store MySQL scripts in that. And this file can be managed in Visual Studio and can be synchronized with TFS. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes. You can evaluate whether this method is suitable for your actual situation.